# How to get complete available resources from a web page using jsoup in java

Tags: java, jsoup

I need to download all the available images from the web page.

I am using **Jsoup** to traverse through the web page.
If the image is included in the page using `<img>` then I am able to download it.
I have seen in some web page that the image is been assigned from css, in that case then how can we download the image using **Jsoup** in **Java**

If anyone knows please help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: I wrote a class for this: https://github.com/JonasCz/save-for-offline/blob/master/app/src/main/java/jonas/tool/saveForOffline/PageSaver.java Look at the bottom for the code which parses the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Since Jsoup is a HTML parser, it's of litle help here. What you need is a CSS parser.

You can use Jsoup to find the URLs to the CSS. If inline styles are used you can also use Jsoup to find them.

Comment: It means that I have to get the source link and suppose to traverse to that link, is it so ?